# How to display unique content per each user logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried and tried and I just can't figure it out. I am trying to display different content based on the user logged on. I currently have a whole login system setup.

For example, I want to display "This content is for testuser". That content should ONLY be viewable by testuser. I also want different content displayed for the user "anotheruser2"...anotheruser2 should see "This content is for anotheruser2".

I'm only going to have a few users registered...

Here is the current code I have, but it doesn't work at all...

```
<?php
if ( $session->logged_in ) {
  if ( $username = admin ) {
echo "testadmin";
  } elseif ( $username = testuser ) {
echo "test";
  } else {
// anyone else
  }
} else {
  // guests
}
?>
```

Any help? It would be much appreciated...I'm still learning PHP so some things to end up stumping me (like this!)

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use == (double equals), single equals assigns the value to the left-hand variable, e.g. `$username = "admin"` will set the value of $username to admin whereas `$username == "admin"` will test whether $username is equal to admin returning a true/false result.

You also need to wrap your user name comparisons in quotes to compare strings (as I assume you don't have constants set-up).

```
<?php
if ( $session->logged_in ) {
  if ( $username == "admin" ) {
echo "testadmin";
  } elseif ( $username == "testuser" ) {
echo "test";
  } else {
// anyone else
  }
} else {
  // guests
}
?>
```